# Colors of Buttons in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a small little test software using Tkinter. I'm trying to color a button red, and when you click on it, it turns green.

There seem to be similar questions asked, but none of them made any difference.

```
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title('Test Software')
root.resizable(width = False, height = False)
root.geometry("300x300")

HandleBarButton = ttk.Button(text = "Handle Bars", bg = "red", command = handleBarCommand)
HandleBarButton.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

parkingStallButton = ttk.Button(text = "Parking Stalls", bg = "red", command = parkingStallsCommand)
parkingStallButton.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

toiletButton = ttk.Button(text = "Toilets", bg = "red", command = toiletsCommand)
toiletButton.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

doorsButton = ttk.Button(text = "Doors", bg = "red", command = doorsCommand)
doorsButton.grid(row = 0, column = 3)
```

I have commands defined above, but It's not essential to my question. 
When I run this, it gives the error :

```
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-bg"
```

Any help on this? 
Thanks.

Comment: We will need to see your imports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because bg option is not supported in ttk button constructor.You can change the background color easily if you use a normal tkinter button.

```
HandleBarButton= tkinter.Button(root,text = "Handle Bars", bg = "red", command = handleBarCommand)
```

or if  really want to use ttk buttons,you can try changing the style database using,

```
ttk.Style().configure("TButton", padding=6, relief="flat",background="red")

HandleBarButton = ttk.Button(text = "Handle Bars", bg = "red", command = handleBarCommand)
```

But the second method may not give you the desired result.